# CrossAxisAlignment does not center column widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and I have been trying to center my column widgets just to grasp an understanding of the layouts but the CrossAxisAlignment property of the Column doesn't seem to work.

I have tried enclosing the column into several other widgets like container but the solutions I have found so far just overwrite the core functionality of CrossAxisAlignment property.
If I wrap the entire the Column in a Center widget then it is centered on the horizontal axis by default and CrossAxisAlignment property wouldn't work.

The only solution I found was to wrap the column in a container and setting its width property to take up entire width of the screen but that seems like brute forcing the layout instead of using the dynamic behaviour of Flutter.

```dart
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        leading: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back_ios,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
      color: Colors.grey[500],
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: FlutterLogo(
              size: 60.0,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: FlutterLogo(
              size: 60.0,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.purple,
            child: FlutterLogo(
              size: 60.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
);
```

**Output**:

[image: Column uncentered]

Only by hard setting the width property does it center properly

```dart
Container(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

**Output**:

[image: Column Centered]

My question is is there a better way to use CrossAxisAlignment property without manually fixing the width? 
And in what use cases does it actually work without any wrapper code?

Answer (score 11):

The thing is: the `CrossAxisAlignment` works, but your column is only as wide as it shows on the image. This way it looks like nothing is happening.

To get your items in the center of the screen, you have to move your entire Column to the center. You can achieve this by wrapping your column inside an `Align` widget and setting `alignment: Alignment.center`.

Answer (score 3):

Add `alignment`

```
body: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If property ***CrossAxisAlignment*** doesn't work, you can wrap your widget in Row and set `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center`. It isn't the best solution for this problem, because we create extra widget.

Answer (score 1):

I have wrapped with `Center`: -Flutter 3.0

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can do this also. 
1. width = _width,
2. alignment = Alignment.center,

```
 double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
 Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    elevation: 0.0,
    leading: Icon(
      Icons.arrow_back_ios,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
  ),
  body: Container(
    width = _width,
    alignment = Alignment.center,
    color: Colors.grey[500],
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.orange,
          child: FlutterLogo(
            size: 60.0,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: FlutterLogo(
            size: 60.0,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.purple,
          child: FlutterLogo(
            size: 60.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
);
```