# Why are my widgets not in the center of the screen?

Tags: css, android-studio, flutter, dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        'BMI:',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50.0),
      ),
      FlatButton(
        child: Text('GO BACK'),
        color: Colors.grey,
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
);}
```

I just want the text and button to be in the center of the screen vertically and horizontally. I put main and cross axis alignment to center, but the column is on the left side of the screen, although it has centered vertically. Just not horizontally; I thought that's what crossaxisalignment is for, why doesn't that center it?

Comment: If I wrap the column in a center widget it works, why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is: the CrossAxisAlignment works, but your column is only as wide as it shows on the image. This way it looks like nothing is happening.

thereFore you can wrap the whole column widget inside the center widget to make it working.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'BMI:',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50.0,),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('GO BACK'),
              color: Colors.grey,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

For more info take a look at this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57322803/crossaxisalignment-does-not-center-column-widgets).
Hope it will help.

Tip:- Use Flutter Inspector in android studio to get the correct ideas about the widget position and alignment.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the column's width is as wide as it's biggest child, meaning if you don't have a very wide element it will position everything else in the center according to the widest child
so if you added :

```
Container(width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
```

to your Column children that should also fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

using the inspector tool in Android studio, the column is not taking the device's full width.

[image]

So you can either wrap it in center widget:

```
Center(
  child:Column(children:[...],...)
  );
```

or wrap it in a container and specify a height.

```
Container(
  height: value,
  child:Column(children:[...],...)
  );
```